# What is this red glassy rock

Tags: geology, rocks

I found rocks looking like this in my backyard but cant get to know what they are or how to find out. Below are pictures[image: rock1]
[image: rock 2]
[image: rock 3]
I don’t know if there’s more info I should mention. If there’s anything please advise

Comment: with the abundance of information you give in your question it should be easy to identify it(absolutely no information at all),sadly rock id question are off topic.

Comment: It might be some quartz contamined with some metal oxide?

Comment: I remember, I've already seen this rock! It is sold as a so-named "salt lamp": https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/10554/10553217/images/res_2bf7b2a0cf3586ce40670cbe3963c42f.jpg

Comment: Could you please break some little dust from the rock, and taste it? I believe it should be salty.

Comment: I know I didn’t give any info. But this isn’t my domain. If there is anything I can try or report please tell me. I don’t even know if posting such a question violates this site’s regulations. Although i’m not offended or anything, but I think the sarcasm might hurt someone else. Thanks for commenting @trondhansen

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica what you’re referring to is (i think) Himalayan salt. This is not the case

Comment: The my first idea (contaminated quartz) remains. I hope you get an answer yet before the closure.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/red-and-pink-minerals-1440941) for some ideas.  You may want to do some testing, at least for Mohs hardness.  But comparing your samples to the typical pictures shown in the referenced site I would guess an alkali feldspar (hardness = 6)  or perhaps rose quartz (hardness =7).  Note the hardnesses, a steel file falls in between at 6.5.